# I want to use Widget.Button.Transparent style with my button

Tags: android, android-button

> error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'style' with value '@android:style/Widget.Button.Transparent').,style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Transparent"

Answer (score 1):

I have bad news.  The Android API is white-listed.  Only object that are listed in $ANDROID_SRC/frameworks/base/api/NN.txt are visible to client applications running on API level NN.

While the three other button styles found in styles.xml are all exposed, Widget_Button_Transparent is not.  You can't use it.